# ASP.NET Core razor view doesn't show up in browser

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

This is what the browser shows me:

[image: browser error]

This is my `_Layout`:

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer _localizer

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>@_localizer[(string)ViewData["Title"]] - Accounter</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="icons/site.webmanifest">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css"/>
    
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.412/styles/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.412/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-action="Index">Tasker</a>
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Authentication" asp-action="LogOut">@_localizer["Log out"]</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Authentication" asp-action="Index">@_localizer["Log in"]</a>
                }
            </div>
            <partial name="_SelectLanguagePartial"/>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div></div>
<div class="vh-100 pt-5 backdrop">
    <div class="container rounded-3 p-3">
        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cdc2f29cb5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

I require user to be authenticated and redirect to the authentication page in `ConfigureServices`.

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Authentication";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

`AuthenticationController`:

```
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationBL _authenticationBL;

        public AuthenticationController(IAuthenticationBL authenticationBL)
        {
            _authenticationBL = authenticationBL;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([Bind("Email", "Password")] AuthenticationVM vm)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Index", vm);
            await _authenticationBL.RegisterAsync(vm.Email, vm.Password, Request);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "GeneralInformation");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn([Bind("Email", "Password")] AuthenticationVM vm)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Index", vm);
            await _authenticationBL.LogInAsync(vm.Email, vm.Password, User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "GeneralInformation");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
        {
            await _authenticationBL.LogoutAsync(User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Authentication Index view:

```
@model Web.Models.VMs.AuthenticationVM
@inject IViewLocalizer _localizer
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Authentication";
}

<div class="card w-50 container justify-content-center">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="text-center mb-3">@_localizer["Log in"]</h5>
        <form asp-controller="Authentication" id="authentication-form">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-4 row">
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email">
                <label asp-for="Email">@_localizer["Email"]</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-4 row">
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <label asp-for="Password">@_localizer["Password"]</label>
                <i class="btn fa-solid fa-eye" id="password-toggle"></i>
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <button type="submit" class="col-sm-5 btn btn-primary" asp-action="Register">@_localizer["Register"]</button>
                <button type="submit" class="col-sm-5 btn btn-primary" asp-action="LogIn">@_localizer["Log in"]</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/authentication.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Can your application work without  authentication ?

Comment: May I ask at which step did your problem occur? What is your operation process like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I deleted the indication of default action in `Startup`:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action}");
});
```

The framework wasn't able to understand what action to invoke on redirection to a controller, and I didn't get a page. Fix:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```